# Import ECC key in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to import a private and public signing key in C#. They are both elliptic curve secp521. The public key looks like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGbMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjA4GGAAQA7WeRuZKFy1T3i4kmoNY2xAaWwAu7YI6aZUvWg/Hm
7Tf+0n7StfGtHlf0jkMLLtjF1Yv1FCKOGlJ+vIt0K1hI9wkA2BjmrjpMUqplBkmRklDOp5TEF9ss
laaPkr0wWf3WdmwvGTNIP1R3uvbSTEgvI02VS4Bz/f8Z4qzf3ZbAsBcLzBc=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Tried importing with:

```
pubkey = pubkey.Substring(27, pubkey.Length-27-25); // remove wrapping
byte[] pkcs8Blob = Base64.Decode(pubkey);
CngKey k = CngKey.Import(pkcs8Blob, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
```

But this gives me the error "The parameter is incorrect" and nothing more. Any one got a idea, how to fix this?

Update:
Realized it's only the private key that is pkcs8 so now trying with this:

```
X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(pkcs8Blob);
```

In java it's done like this:

```
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8Blob);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm, "SC");
ECPublicKey pubKey = (ECPublicKey) fact.generatePublic(spec);
```

Comment: Does pubkey have carriage returns in it when you look at it in the debugger?

Comment: Not after the "dewrapper"

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `\n` at the beginning then change:

```
pubkey = pubkey.Substring(27, pubkey.Length-27-25);
```

to this:

```
pubkey = pubkey.Substring(26, pubkey.Length-26-25);
```

With `27` the first character gets cut off.

Comment: @user1930848 I forgot about the second parameter. Try now.

Comment: In decoding or during key import? Because this `System.Convert.FromBase64String(pubkey);` works for me.

Comment: It's key import, same as earlier.

Comment: No inner exception? Also please verify under the debugger that bytes are ok (it's enough to check the first and the last byte here).

Comment: No same exception. With 26 in the substring: first bytes are 48,129,155,48,16,6,7   last 176, 23, 11, 204, 23

Comment: That was in the byte array, pubkey gives: "MIGbMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjA4GGAAQA7WeRuZKFy1T3i4kmoNY2xAaWwAu7YI6aZUvWg/Hm\n7Tf+0n7StfGtHlf0jkMLLtjF1Yv1FCKOGlJ+vIt0K1hI9wkA2BjmrjpMUqplBkmRklDOp5TEF9ss\nlaaPkr0wWf3WdmwvGTNIP1R3uvbSTEgvI02VS4Bz/f8Z4qzf3ZbAsBcLzBc="

Comment: All right, great, but the bytes won't tell me anything. They should tell you - verify them against the original key. And perhaps update your question after you've gained all the new information.

Comment: original key? I've found one problem the pub key is a X509Certificate but still the private key does not work :(